# Python evdev equivalent for Windows 10

Tags: python, python-2.7, windows-10, evdev

Is there a Windows-10 64 bit evdev equivalent that can be directly installed from the Anaconda command line? Example:

```
[Anaconda2] C:\Users\User>conda install -c auto evdev_equivalent
```

Attempts to install pyHook from the anaconda command line was unsuccessful:

```
[Anaconda2] C:\Users\User>anaconda search -t conda pyhook
Using Anaconda Cloud api site https://api.anaconda.org
Run 'anaconda show <USER/PACKAGE>' to get more details:
No packages found
     Name                      |  Version | Package Types   | Platforms
     ------------------------- |   ------ | --------------- | ---------------
Found 0 packages
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to wrangle raw input across platforms, you *might* want to look at existing solutions to handle the platform differences for you. This allows you to maintain a single code base and not deal with platform differences that might effectively force you to implement for every supported platform. Or even worse, One implementation for everything and one Windows-only implementation with an `if`-wrapped conditional import.

You could look into using [SDL2](https://www.libsdl.org/) for which [there are Python bindings](https://github.com/py-sdl/py-sdl2). And according to the docs, it [should work with Python 2.7](https://pysdl2.readthedocs.io/en/0.9.16/install.html#prerequisites) (though I really hope one would opt for a more modern Python version in this day and age)

If you're worried about the requirement of having SDL2 available for your users, there's [a lib package](https://pypi.org/project/pysdl2-dll/) for that as well.